# Reading Line by Line in C++ for Pairs

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have an input file that looks something like this:

```
 0.1   239.402
 0.4.   32342.34
 0.7   4.924939
 and so on...
```

I am trying to read it line by line using the fstream extraction operator >>
I need a way to set a while loop condition that would stop at the end of the file, and I need a way to push the two as a pair onto two stacks
The stacks are previously implemented in a class file Stack as linked lists
I currently have something like

```
double a, double b
std::string t;
Stack av;
Stack bv;
while(i>>a>>t>>b&&(t=="\t"){
   av.push(a);
   bv.push(b);
}
```

i know i'm incorrect as it's not always a tab space gap. also the file starts with a couple of spaces until the first row and then has a random number of spaces until the second row, and then a next line.
Is there a way to write a program where it knows when there is a double to read and use the random number of whitespaces as separation between a and b?

I hope this makes sense! Thanks so much for your help as I'm a beginner.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JasonLiam i just did

Comment: `operator >>` for `std::istream` ignores all whitespace by default. All you need is `i >> a >> b` (assuming the file is indeed exactly as you described and you trust it).

Comment: is the 2nd line extra dot in the file, or is that a typeo?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: You meant `i >> a >> b`, didn't you ;-) ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Indeed! Was too quick to copy ;)

Comment: @Nathaniel See [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/-ds502JIik).